# how to set path in bashrc for multiple locations

Tags: bash

I am installing same library (maybe with different release versions) at two different locations. Now I am exporting the path in bashrc for both. In linux which one is taken if I call the library in some program?
For example:
mylib_version1 is installed in /home/PATH1/lib ,
mylib_version2 is installed in /home/PATH2/lib

in bashrc I do,

```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/PATH1/lib
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/PATH2/lib
```

which path is actually taken by some other program when calling this library? How does the ordering work in bashrc?

Similarly what happens when PATH1 is just /usr/local/lib (which I don't export in bashrc)
and PATH2 is some user define path.
What I experience for  some program is, if I install it in /usr/local/bin
and if I install using some prefix like /home/PATH/bin and export it in bashrc like 
        export PATH=$PATH:/home/PATH/bin

it always takes from /usr/local/bin.

Comment: hi, that is my question, if I do (for example) which lhapdf, it returns the path /usr/local/bin/lhapdf even though I have it in both places in /usr/local/bin/ and in some predefined place like PATH2 (which is exported in bashrc but not taken)

Comment: Whichever comes first. In this case it is `/home/PATH1/lib`.

Comment: Using `export` more than once is completely redundant.

Comment: @4ae1e1  What happens if one of the path is /usr/local/lib (which is not in bashrc ) and other is /home/PATH1/lib (which is in .bashrc)?
I see that it always takes from /usr/local/lib. Is there any way to take from bashrc i.e. the /home/PATH1/lib ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have `library.so` with 2 versions and you have a binary that might use `library.so` version 1 or 2.

To deal with that problem you must first understand the meaning of libraries version mechanism. All libraries should be placed in the same place and you might have something like that:

```
/usr/lib/library.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/library.so.2.0.0
```

Your binary would be linked to the correct library based on the API used and linking during the build process.

Please read more information regarding libraries [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Versioning.html)